# Nginx return an empty json object with fake 200 status code

Tags: json, performance, nginx

We've got an API running on Nginx, supposed to return JSON objects. This server has a lot of load so we did a lot of performance improvements.

The API recieves an ID from the client. The server has a bunch of files representing these IDs. So if the ID is found as a file, the contents of that file (Which is JSON) will be returned by the backend. If the file does not exists, no backend is called, Nginx simple sends a 404 for that, so we save performance (No backend system has to run).

Now we stumbled upon a problem. Due to old systems we still have to support, we cannot hand out a 404 page for clients as this will cause problems. What I came up with, is to return an empty JSON string instead (`{}`) with a 'fake' 200 status code. This needs to be a highly performant solution to still be able to handle all the load.

Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Comment: If you got that far to return a 404 (based on the condition whether the file is present or not), why not return the desired response (empty JSON object) with status code 200 instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
error_page 404 =200 @empty_json;

location @empty_json {
     return 200 "{}";
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/error_page
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: how can i return the specific response i got from a proxy server?
if i used a module auth_subrequest

Comment: In your example the Content-Type header is set to application/octet-stream. I cannot figure out how to change the Content-Type.  add_header add another Content-Type instead of replacing it

Comment: @jmcollin92 Check the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type  It seems you have set this directive to `application/octet-stream` somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: No I haven't. I found a solution with this line : more_set_headers -t 'application/octet-stream' 'Content-Type: application/json'; It requires to add nginx-extras package (apt-get install nginx-extras)

Comment: @jmcollin92 You should set the `default_type` directive. That's it. You don't need any extras.

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a file in your document root called e.g. `empty.json` which only contains an empty object `{}`

Then in your nginx configuration add this line in your location block

```
try_files $uri /empty.json;
```

( read more about [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) )

This will check if the file requested by the client exists and if it does not exist it just shows empty.json instead. This produces a 200 HTTP OK and shows a `{}` to the requesting client.